# Disable ListBoxItem based on the DataContext of another element in the window

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a ListBox with a bunch of items in it. I also have another ListBox with a bunch of items in it. The two are related to each in other, in that if the user selects an item from ListBox1, a corresponding item will be created in ListBox2. If the item exists in ListBox2, I want the corresponding item in ListBox1 to be disabled, so that the user can only have one of these items in ListBox2.

I've noticed some shortfalls with Silverlight compared to WPF in that you can't use ItemContainerStyle bindings, and you can't use RelativeSources... These are exactly the two things that first came to mind when trying to do it (having a null-to-enabled converter on the relative source of the ListBox DataContext (this DataContext would hold the collection of items for ListBox2).

So for example:

ListBox1 has items:

```
Red
Blue
Yellow
```

ListBox2 has 1 item currently:

```
RedCar
```

I have Red corresponding to RedCar, so would want Red to be disabled in ListBox1, and have Blue and Yellow enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an event for when the user clicks on the 'add new' button. At that point an event is called that looks at what systems are in the second listbox, and then disables any of the corresponding items. I wouldn't normally like to have UI-esque code in the ViewModel, but in this particular case it's a one-off, and works rather well. Since I'm data-binding, there is really only one piece of UI code in there anyway, and that's getting the ListBoxItem to enable/disable using:

`var lbi = (ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(member);`

I have a reference to the ListBox as that's the control that called the action.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with 2 sets of [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). One you start with { Red, Blue, Yellow } and the other empty. On each event you're capturing to do your action, probbly [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged.aspx), you write code to remove from one of the collections and add to the other.

Considering

```
var Box2Collection = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
var Box2Collection = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
```

On the SelectionChanged event handler

```
Box2Collection.Add(selectedColor);
Box1Collection.Remove(selectedColor);
```

You can also either write code to insert them in the correct order, or use [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) to keep the Lists sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a binding to the `IsEnabled` property on your items with a converter that took the `SelectedItem` from the list box.

```
 public object ConvertTo(object value, Type targetType,
     object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
 {
     Vehicle vehicle = (Vehicle)parameter;
     if (vehicle == null) return true;

     Color currentColor = (Color)value;
     return vehicle.Color != currentColor;
 }
```